# What causes Visual Studio's text editor navigation bar to become gigantic?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've been working on a project lately where one particular TypeScript file, but no other files, causes the Navigation Bar dropdowns to become ridiculously large.  What would cause this, and how can I fix it?  See below.

[image]

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1046435/source-editor-methodlist-combobox-way-too-large

Comment: @HansPassant That's not the problem OP is observing.